# SQL Server Script Quick Replace all found strings with incrementing integer

Tags: sql-server

I have large `INSERT` SQL script that I want to modify it with quick replace. By replacing each found string with interger, where every next integer is previous integer+1.

Before:

```
INSERT Compartment (CompartmentID) VALUES ('A')
INSERT Compartment (CompartmentID) VALUES ('B')
```

After:

```
INSERT Compartment (CompartmentID) VALUES (1)
INSERT Compartment (CompartmentID) VALUES (2)
```

I know how to find the specific strings, but I can't find anywhere syntax or way have to replace it incrementing integers.

Comment: Is it just A-Z? What value does the 30th record get, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all you char CompartmentID with ordered numbers like this:

```
declare @Compartment table(CompartmentID varchar(10), name varchar(10), intID int)
INSERT INTO @Compartment(CompartmentID, name) values
    ('a', 'a')
    , ('b', 'b')
    , ('c', 'c')
    , ('d', 'd')
    , ('e', 'e')

UPDATE c SET CompartmentID = o.ID
FROM @Compartment c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CompartmentID, ID = ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY CompartmentID) 
    FROM @Compartment
) o ON c.CompartmentID = o.CompartmentID

SELECT * FROM @Compartment
```

**Output:**

```
CompartmentID   name
1               a
2               b
3               c
4               d
5               e
```

It would be better to create a new column of type int or change the type of CompartmentID once the update is finished.

You should also use an identity column if you want the numbers to be incremented automaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to handle empty string. You can select the rows where CompartmentID contains a character that isnt a numeric and update the result set like this:

```
DECLARE @Compartment table(CompartmentID varchar(20))
INSERT @Compartment(CompartmentID) VALUES ('A'),('A'),('B'),('1'),('A1')


-- EDIT: Changed answer

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT CompartmentID, DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY CompartmentID) rn
  FROM @Compartment
  --WHERE CompartmentID LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR CompartmentID = ''
)
UPDATE CTE
SET CompartmentID = rn
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
CompartmentID
2
2
4
1
3
```

Note: Now all id will CompartmentID changed(also the numeric CompartmentID), identical values for old CompartmentID will get identical numeric values.

Comment: You might end up with duplicate IDs if you don't match numeric value?

Comment: yes, as described in my Note at the end of the answer

Comment: @JulienVavasseur it is unclear to me whether the numeric values should also be replaced. That is why I chose this solution. If this is not correct, all that has to be done is removing the where clause. There can always be weakness in the answer if the question wasn't specified. You could argue that your solution would be too slow to execute if there were 10000 rows with same CompartmentID(although it does sound unique)

Comment: I agree with you, Lots of assumtions. With both answers and comments, he should be able to make it work.